# Как изменить значение по умолчанию у параметра lazy на глобальном уровне в SQLAlchemy.relationship()

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

В SQLAlchemy у функции relationship() параметр lazy по умолчанию имеет значение "select".
Есть ли возможность на глобальном уровне установить другое значение по умолчанию?

Чтобы было проще понимать, что я имею ввиду, вот абстрактный вариант того что я хочу сделать:

```py
    engine = create_engine(
        url=db_settings.DSN,
        lazy_defaults='joined'
    )
```